# Trying not to use 'if' in NginX, but how?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, web-server, redis

I read that **if** is evil and should not be used in NginX config. But how can I rewrite my code, so that I don't use the if ? What I want to do is: NginX are supposed to call Redis instead of php if there is a special request "foobar.php" AND a special argument called "magicargument". When redis fails NginX proxy_passes to PHP. It work's, but only when I use if's!

Here is the config

```
    location ~ foobar.php$ {
            default_type   application/json;
            error_page 404 = @redisfailed;

            if ($args = "")
            {
                     return 404;
            }

            if ($arg_magicargument = false)
            {
                    return 404;
            }

            set $redis_key $args;
            redis_pass     127.0.0.1:6379;
    }

    location @redisfailed
    {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: Note: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/ says "The only 100% safe things which may be done inside if in a location context are: `return ...;` and `rewrite ... last;`. You're doing that, so it'd appear to be safe to use. Note also that the IfIsEvil page indicates that the behavior is consistent, so if you've tested this and it's working, you can count on that being the case.

Comment: Also from that page: "There are cases where you simply cannot avoid using an if, for example, if you need to test a variable which has no equivalent directive."

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `return` is safe to use with `if`. So I don't need to worry ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the redis application, you could check `magicargument` / other arguments there, and use only a simple `location` block in your nginx configuration without `if` statements.

BTW. Your `location` statement matches every URL that ends with `foobar.php`, for example `http://www.example.com/nonexistingdirectory/foobar.php`. You might want to be more specific, like `location = /foobar.php` to process only requests with `foobar.php` in the root URI.